# How to display JSONObject into TextView on android

Tags: java, php, json, android-studio

I've set up a php script to create json [here](http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php), but when i try to display the JSONobject i got some error like this on my Android Monitor..

> Value (html)(body)(script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

can someone tell me how to fix it? below my code to try

> my MainActivity.java

```js
package flix.yudi.okhttp1;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ask = c.getString("ask");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("ask", ask);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"ask"}, new int[]{R.id.ask});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

> my HttpHandler.java

```js
package flix.yudi.okhttp1;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I got the reference code from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

someone can help me how to fix the error?

> Edited code

```js
if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray pertanyaan = jsonObj.getJSONArray("pertanyaan");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < pertanyaan.length(); i++) {
                        JSONArray c = pertanyaan.getJSONArray(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ask = c.getString("ask");
```

> Edit

```
Error
```

```js
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
E/MainActivity: Response from url: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
<script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function
toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}
var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("455e95bd78dbe99a933749187199f824");
document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
location.href="http://zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
E/MainActivity: Json parsing error: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
V/RenderScript: 0x5598622250 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
```

Comment: It looks like, data you are receiving in `String jsonStr` is not valid `JSON`. It has html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to server then you could make it return a string in the following format:

> {"contacts":[{"id":"1","ask":"pertanyaan ke 1"},{"id":"2","ask":"pertanyaan ke 2"},{"id":"3","ask":"pertanyaan ke 3"},{"id":"4","ask":"pertanyaan ke 4"},{"id":"5","ask":"pertanyaan ke 5"}]}

if you want to read it as `JSONObject` with `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);`

and then use  `JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");` to parse it

---

After your edits:

Change this `JSONArray c = pertanyaan.getJSONArray(i);` to this `JSONObject c = pertanyaan.getJsonObject(i)`

Comment: yes sir, i know that -({"contacts":[{)- must be showed, but i dont have an idea how to showing my table into json, althrough i've tried to search it in go*gle,
so, about ur idea to replace JSONObject to JSONArray, i did it, but get some error in " String id = c.getString("id"); and String ask = c.getString("ask");, " with the error say "getString (int) in JSONArray cannot be applied"

Comment: JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray pertanyaan = jsonObj.getJSONArray("pertanyaan");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < pertanyaan.length(); i++) {
                        JSONArray c = pertanyaan.getJSONArray(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ask = c.getString("ask");

Comment: You need to parse the internal `JSONObjects` when looping though the `JSONArray`

Comment: your updated code let my error gone, but my JSONArray pertanyaan = jsonObj.getJSONArray("pertanyaan"); still get the same error like that,
i've been try to change JSONArray into JSONObject, but its make my code error in looping,,

Comment: not yet sir, i just want to display my question from database into text view,

Comment: and I've been looking for a lot of methods to do, but i didn't find out some methods to solve my problem, i've been looking to use OkHttp, Volley, Gson,etc library, but everytime i try to create the code i've got from internet, i always get an error, 
can you help me a simple code to displaying database value into android sir?

Comment: i suggest you delete your previous code aand post your updated code and your error. Or consider asking a new question with your updated code and error.

Comment: i've create a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199853/android-how-to-show-display-jsonarray-into-textview),,
do you have an idea sir?

Answer (score 0):

Your server response is JsonArray But your trying to parse as Json Object

Change

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

To

```
 JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

And create the next oprations as JSONArray and not as JSONObject

Comment: i've change all my code from JSONObject into JSONArray, but when i did it some code showing error "getString (int) in JSONArray cannot be applied" on String id = c.getString("id"); and String ask = c.getString("ask");,

i've been read about the error in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517596/android-java-type-org-json-jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759464/getjsonarray-in-graphresponse-cannot-be-applied-to-java-lang-string-facebook) but still dont have an idea to fix it