# ANDROID - how to show/display JSONArray into TextView

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

i try to display JSONArray from this [link](http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php),,
but when i try to running the app, that app popup an error like this
[image: Screenshot_2016-10-22-15-52-56-359_flix.yudi.okh.png]

i try to enable javascript and search it from internet, almost all of them told me to using WebView, but i just using Textview

```
MainActivity.java
```

```js
package flix.yudi.okhttp1;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ask = c.getString("ask");

                        HashMap<String, String> pertanyaans = new HashMap<>();

                        pertanyaans.put("id", id);
                        pertanyaans.put("ask", ask);

                        contactList.add(pertanyaans);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"ask"}, new int[]{R.id.ask});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

```
HttpHandler.java
```

```js
package flix.yudi.okhttp1;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

> send_data.php

```html
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $query = "select id,ask from pertanyaan";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] =$r;
  }
echo json_encode(array_values($rows));

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

can someone help me how to solve the error?

> EDIT RESPONSE FROM SERVER

[GET](http://prnt.sc/cxrwgd) [POST](http://prntscr.com/cxrwrf)

Comment: Please add the response you get from the server

Comment: @ReazMurshed Done Sir, can u check it out?

Comment: What is the log output of `Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);`. Maybe the web service calling is returning an error (html)page so you're not getting the JSON response in first place.

Comment: suggest `catch (final JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace()}`. Check your log for exception

Comment: how to see the log output of `Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);` sir??
from logcat sir?

Comment: @Flix Yes! You can grab the log output from there.

Comment: @Raghunandan can u tell me how to check the log??
in `logcat` i didn't see everything, just blank screen on `logcat` sir

Comment: you check the log in android studio - > Android monitor -> logcat

Comment: this is the screenshot of my logcat when i running the program, [link](http://prntscr.com/cxs3lg), i didn't see any error sir

Comment: **org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray** This is not a valid response that you expect. You want a json array. You just use `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Your url opens fine in a browser. See if you request should add some header. Check on server side that returns data fro the mobile request. You can log the server response on the server side and check

Comment: To be sure i mocked your rest api. try this url **http://www.mocky.io/v2/580c5a121000006c06540447** with the same android code it works fine. So check the server php code. Nothing to do with android

Comment: @Raghunandan i've try it too sir with ur URL, its work fine, but how to make my table `ask` displaying like that? do you have a reference code of php to convert it to JSON sir?
but i got some error in logcat although the application is running,
`E/MarketConnection:Network Error : 400` `E/MarketConnection:Connection failed : SERVER_ERROR` `E/MarketConnection:Connection Exception for resolver.gslb.mi-idc.com :java.net.SocketTimeoutException` `E/MarketConnection:Connection failed : NETWORK_ERROR`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126438/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-flix).

Comment: @MikeM. is this so cookie-centric of an issue or if not do you have another potential reference

Comment: @Drew That question is from the same user. It's the same as this question, just with less information, posted after this one, when apparently someone suggested they do so, for some reason. They accepted the answer there, so I'm assuming they got their solution. I just voted it a possible dupe to give them the opportunity to close it themselves, if they don't wanna delete it. If they are asking something different here, then it will kinda nudge them to edit it to improve it. As it stands, the only question in both is "Why am I getting this Json parsing error?"

Comment: @MikeM. thx, sorry, I was blind to that fact !