# ANDROID&PHP - Why am I getting this JSONArray parsing error

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I've tried various methods to display data from MySQL into android with PHP and JSON from my hosting [here](http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php), but always getting error like this
[image: Screenshot_2016-10-22-15-52-56-359_flix.yudi.okh.png]

but when i request another [link](http://www.mocky.io/v2/580c6b89100000f60754044a) with the same JSON result, its work fine

i've tried to find out, and i suggested to enable `JavaScript` in my hosting, but i didn't find out the reference how to enable `JavaScript` in my hosting,

here is the `PHP` code to `encode_JSON`

```js
<?php
    include 'dbconfig.php';
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "select id,ask from pertanyaan";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    echo json_encode(array_values($rows));

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

did i using wrong code to encode_json from PHP?

`EDITED AFTER ADD  header('Content-Type: application/json');`

`LogCat` notif

```js
10-24 14:16:09.010 17727-17749/flix.yudi.okhttp1 E/MainActivity: Response from url: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("455e95bd78dbe99a933749187199f824");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
10-24 14:16:09.010 17727-17749/flix.yudi.okhttp1 E/MainActivity: Json parsing error: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
10-24 14:16:09.161 17727-17746/flix.yudi.okhttp1 V/RenderScript: 0x55abdd14e0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
```

Comment: Call the script in a browser and check if it's a valid json, it seems that you include html tags in the response. Instead of outputting an error string set an appropriate header code like 500

Comment: share android code

Comment: @ka_lin how to check if the link is a valid json? i tried the response [here](http://prnt.sc/cxrwgd)

Comment: @PhanVanLinh i've shared the android code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199853/android-how-to-show-display-jsonarray-into-textview?noredirect=1#comment67677815_40199853)

Comment: please share the content of Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

Comment: your data contains the html tags, so you are getting this error while parsing.

Comment: i didn't had a notif from logcat, just blank screen

Comment: @Flix try learn how to display the logcat, without logcat you can not debug and find problem

Comment: so how can I change the data contains of html tags?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh this is the [screenshot link](http://prnt.sc/cxs3lg) about the logcat, but thanks for the advice

Comment: with your screenshot. I'm sure Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr); will print a log in your logcat. Please check it carefully. Beside that, please check the Nakul answer, it seem like correct

Comment: @PhanVanLinh do you have any idea about my error? now that `Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);` show me an error, and i've been edited my post above about the logcat error after add ` header('Content-Type: application/json');` from Nakul answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared given two request. You haven't  set the header in PHP script as JSON.
For setting Content-type header as JSON, put following code in PHP script

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

It will work.
There is not error in your android code, as the 2nd url gives the desired result. Also I don't think there is any problem while encoding JSON.

While comparing two links check the `Content-type` header in request, both are different.
[image]

[image]

Comment: still getting the same error sir, but i think it should correct

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/it-looks-like-this-is-a-web-page-not-a-feed-i-looked-for-a-feed-associated/

I think the problem is related to your hosting environment.
Its blocking non browser access to your page.

Comment: I'm assuming your using OkHttp library for communication.
try adding userAgent header from library.
something like this "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"

It will pretend that requesting agent is browser.
I hope this will work.

Comment: ohh maybe, cause i just using a free hosting to create,
thanks for useful answer and help me @nakul

Comment: for now, i just use a basic code for communication with the server,
i'm not sure if i can using another library while i didn't know about the basic code,, :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126495/discussion-between-nakul-and-flix).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<?php
    include 'dbconfig.php';
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "select id,ask from pertanyaan";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);


    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        extract($r);
   $rows[] = array(
    "id"=>$id,
   "ask"=>$ask
      );
    }
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo json_encode($rows);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```